# Nested collections Web Api routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

Looking for some help on how I specify the routing and controller setup for the following routes/urls:

```
GET/v1/Expenses
GET/v1/Expenses/5
GET/v1/Expenses/5/Items
GET/v1/Expenses/5/Items/1
```

So far I can quite easily satisfy the first two with the following route and controller methods.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Expenses",
                routeTemplate: "v1/Expenses/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Expenses", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: null,
                handler: new TokenValidationHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
            );
```

And then controller looks like this

```
/* GET v1/expenses */
public IHttpActionResult Get() {
     /*get all expenses*/                
}

/* GET v1/expenses/5 */
public IHttpActionResult Get(long id) {
     /*get expense with id*/
}
```

It's how I satisfy the final 2 routes where I'm struggling, I don't want to use attribute routing as, as far as I'm aware I won't be able to use the per-route message handlers that I need.

I tried the route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ExpenseItems",
                routeTemplate: "v1/Expenses/{id}/Items/{itemId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Expenses", itemId = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: null,
                handler: new TokenValidationHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
            );
```

and the method

```
/* GET v1/expenses/5/items */
public IHttpActionResult GetItems(long id) {
     /*claim items for an expense*/
}
```

But I get the error `Multiple actions were found that match the request` when doing this.

Comment: Hi @Gazeth, I think it would be helpful if you could show which request you're executing when you get that error.

Comment: @BrunoPessanha its when I go to execute http://url/expenses/5/items

Comment: Try this in the second route: `defaults: new { controller = "Expenses", itemId = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "GetItems" }`

Comment: Any success in the suggested approach?